# What is the consequence of using my own autoexec.sas file?

Tags: sas, autoexec

I want to write my own autoexec.sas file, but I don't want to lose any functionality that I might have had from the default autoexec.sas file(s).

When I do a SASHome directory search, I find many files with this name.  Do all of these files execute by default after the SAS system initializes?  Or just one of the files?

Where do I save my own autoexec.sas file so that the other files still execute, along with my own?

Just starting here.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't edit the usermods file.  When you upgrade versions you'll lose all of your changes.  There's actually a specific autoexec file designed just for this purpose -- autoexec_usermods.sas

That's where you'll want to keep your site specific modifications -- this way when you upgrade versions your transition will be relatively seamless.

I think you will want to edit these 3 usermods files:
opt-biserver-Lev1-SASMeta
opt-biserver-Lev1-SASMeta-MetadataServer
opt-biserver-Lev1-SASMeta-WorkspaceServer

Answer (score -1):

The following links from SAS documentation should help answer your question on impact, storage and order of execution of autoexec file :

[Customizing Your SAS Session by Using Configuration and Autoexec Files](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostunx/63053/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p13flc1vsrqwr8n1vutzds8rp3t0.htm)

[Files Used by SAS -> SAS Autoexec File](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63047/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0bmj7wjme32ayn1h4wim7trkhp6.htm)

Comment: Hi Sushil.  These links are useful, but answers with the only information in links are not good answers.  You need to put all of the necessary information to understand the question's answer into the answer itself.